# I am making a medal tally in excel to connect 1 sheet to another

Tags: excel

I am making a medal tally in excel. how do I connect one sheet to another so that if I enter data in sheet 1 then the data should come automatically appear in sheet 2

Answer (score 0):

If you have the value "5" in cell A1 on "Sheet1", then on "Sheet2" you can write "=Sheet1!A1" in cell "B3".

In this way, in cell B3 of "Sheet2" you will always have the value of cell A1 on "Sheet1".

If you will change "5" into "apples", you will see "apples" in B3.